# I am confused by the used of empty parenthesis in python tuple assignment

Tags: python

I am seeing this construct multiple times and wanted to know the meaning of using "()". Also it appears as second argument for the "get" command. What is the benefit of using this over None?

```
from collections import defauldict
f = "A"
q = [(0,f,())] 
g = defaultdict(list)
for l,r,c in edges:
     g[l].append((c,r))
for c,v2 in g.get(v1,()):
     next = c
```

Comment: Ok I corrected that error.

Comment: `()` is just an empty tuple.

Answer (score 1):

Empty parentheses create an empty tuple object. That could be useful if your code expects a tuple (or some iterable), and you don't have any values to include. A `for` loop over an empty tuple will end immediately without running any of the loop body code.

The second argument to `defaultdict.get` (which is inherited from `dict`) is the default value that will be returned, if the requested key is not in the dictionary. Note that for a `defaultdict`, it won't create a new value for the key, like `g[v1]` could.

Comment: What do you mean by default value won't create new value for key ? Ordinary dictionary will create value for key ?

Comment: if you don't supply the second argument to the `get` method, it returns `None`.

Comment: @vkaul11: A `defaultdict` will create a new value (using the factory you gave it when you created it) any time you look up an unknown key with normal indexing syntax (like `g[l]` in the first loop in your code). If you don't want that to happen, you can use `g.get`, which won't create a new value (though it will `return` whatever default value you pass it, or `None` if you don't tell it to use anything in particular).